# How to Make Autoformat Ignore Comments in VS Code

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I love autoformat for Dart in VS Code, but I'd like it to ignore comments.

Here's what I want it to do:
[image: Long comment trails off toward infinity on the right]

But here's what happens when I save and autoformat does its thing:
[image: Nooooo! It split the variable to two lines because of the long comment!]

I want it to autoformat the code as if the comment wasn't there. Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a way to configure [dart-format](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format). Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. The Dart extension formats using [dart_style](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style) which doesn't have this capability (see [FAQ here](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-configure-it)).